# Sticky Service is getting killed when user closes app from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service

I have good concept of starting and using the basic service. I mean not to complicated. In My app I want a service which should not be killed in any situation and should download some files from the server then it should call stopSelf.  I have made my service in the following way. But before sharing its whole code just let me tell you what I am doing

1. In Service I am passing the series of url (string array) which has to download all files from the server.
2. I am using the async task to download from the server.
3. Under this whole process I am getting a 1st response that is in xml then I parse it , and get the JSON string (sorry about that my web service designer is a numb like me). so after these two conversion I store the data in the database and then starts downloading files and saving them to device and store their path in the database. (this all works fine)
4. I am calculating and updating progress in the notification bar. (showing user how much the files has been downloaded)

**what I really want**

I want that my service should not be killed when user removes it from the recent app list , so that it should continue to download and continue to update the status in notification bar. I am using Notification manager to update the progress.

**What is really happening**

When I close my app from recent app tray, I think my service gets killed and the downloading process stops, and It also stops updating the progress of notification in notification bar, Where As I want it to continue to run until the download process is finished.

> Here is my code it is simplified as some methods are really not worthy
>   to be discussed here Such as Parsing the xml or JSON

**Here is the Code**

```
public class MyDemoService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyDemoService";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private LocalBinder m_binder = new LocalBinder();
private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
myAsyncTask myWebFetch;
// Timer to update the ongoing notification
private final long mFrequency = 100;    // milliseconds
private final int TICK_WHAT = 2;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MyDemoService getService() {
        return MyDemoService.this;
    }
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        updateNotification();
        sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this, TICK_WHAT), mFrequency);
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "bound");

    return m_binder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "created");
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Removed");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroyed");
}


public void updateNotification() {
    // Log.d(TAG, "updating notification");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

}


public void hideNotification() {
    Log.d(TAG, "removing notification");
    mNotifyManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    mHandler.removeMessages(TICK_WHAT);
}

public void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");
    mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyDemoService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download)
                    .setContentTitle("SMU")
                    .setContentText("Downloading Images");
    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(MyDemoService.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyDemoService.this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    myWebFetch = new myAsyncTask();
    myWebFetch.execute();
}

class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    MyDB myDB;


    myAsyncTask() {
        myDB = new MyDB(MyDemoService.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
        // Removes the progress bar
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        getJSON("http://*****", 1000000);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public void getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                String readStream = readStream(c.getInputStream());
                if (readStream != null) {
                    JsonParser mJsonParser = new JsonParser(MyDemoService.this);
                    mJsonParser.parseJaSon(readStream);
                    ArrayList<SuitDetails> mImageList = new ArrayList<>(myDB.GetAllData());

                    if (mImageList != null) {
                        //NOW HERE DOWNLOADING IMAGES FROM URL WE GOT SAVED IN DB AFTER PARSING
                        downloadImages(mImageList);

                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        //parsing my input stream and sending back string
        return jsonString.toString();
    }

    void downloadImages(ArrayList<SuitDetails> arrayList) {

        try {

            ArrayList<SuitDetails> imageUrl = arrayList;
            URL url;
            float progressImages = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < imageUrl.size(); i++) {
                progressImages += 100 / imageUrl.size();
                publishProgress((int) progressImages);
                url = new URL(imageUrl.get(i).getPath().toString());
                //create the new connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //set up some things on the connection
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
                urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                //and connect!
                urlConnection.connect();
                File storagePath = new File(MyDemoService.this.getExternalFilesDir("TEST") + "/Mytest");
                storagePath.mkdirs();
                String finalName = imageUrl.get(i).getImageName();
                File myImage = new File(storagePath, finalName + ".png");
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                int downloadedSize = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                }
                //close the output stream when done
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("Status", "1");
                contentValues.put("Path", myImage.getPath().toString());
                myDB.UpdateDownloadStatus(contentValues, imageUrl.get(i).getSImageID());
                fileOutput.close();
            }
            myDB.closeDb();
            //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

> I Know this is length code but sharing if You want to analyse it deeply.

I will provide how I am using and calling this service in MainActivity if you demand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why are you not using an `IntentService` if you want to do network stuff?
2. you should consider adding `setIntentRedelivery(true);` in your constructor

from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#setIntentRedelivery(boolean))

> Sets intent redelivery preferences. Usually called from the
>   constructor with your preferred semantics.
>
> If enabled is true, onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will return
>   START_REDELIVER_INTENT, so if this process dies before
>   onHandleIntent(Intent) returns, the process will be restarted and the
>   intent redelivered. If multiple Intents have been sent, only the most
>   recent one is guaranteed to be redelivered.
>
> If enabled is false (the default), onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)
>   will return START_NOT_STICKY, and if the process dies, the Intent dies
>   along with it.

Comment: how this would cure the service to be be killed when the app is killed as it says in the end 
If enabled is false (the default), onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will return START_NOT_STICKY, and if the process dies, the Intent dies along with it.

Comment: that is why I suggested to set it to true, therefore, killing it will redeliver the intent

Comment: I am sending the url in intent , and when I killed the app it looks like it redelivers , i Have a check if the url is empty , it should stop service and hence it stops the activity , looks like intent gets null or empty

Comment: that is it , I do not know Why am I such an numb , thnaks by the way